# SSL Certificate in my hosting makes me change my java code?

Tags: tls, android, java, web-service

Sorry for my stupid question. But I really want to know what is gonna happen..

I have a webservice hosted over the `http` protocol.

I wanna buy an SSL certificate to have my webservice hosting with the `https` protocol...

Problem is, I have an Android application that is already connected to the web service (the web services is in my hosting with `http`).

The question is: if I buy an SSL certificate and my hosting pass from `HTTP` to `HTTPS`, will I have to change my java code? It will try to change the connect to my server at `http://hosting.esy.es/action.php` to `https://hosting.esy.es/action.php` when the app try to connect to `http` by default the server redirect to `https`?

Because this makes me to change al my http to https in my java code.
If i don't have to change in my code because automatically redirect to https, I already have security pipe?

Thanks for understand me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable SSL/TLS on the server side, the client has to be able to "speak SSL/TLS" too. Otherwise, the connection will end up being reset.

Just changing a web-service to use "https" does not auto-magically change all applications communication encrypted. This is a shared protocol. If I suddenly goes speaking French but you only understand English, communication won't happen. This goes the same way for TLS.

If you enable TLS server side, you will have to modify you apps so that they can also use TLS. Fortunately for you, java has the means to deal easily with TLS using some already defined classes. Just look it up.

On the other hand, you can provide both TLS/SSl enabled traffic for the web (https url) and leave the simple http open as well. So that you can have your website using TLS and your app HTTP only. Then you can proceed to migrate your app over TLS before shutting down your HTTP only channel.

Answer (score 1):

If you configure the server to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, you shouldn't need to modify the application code whatsoever (assuming it will follow a redirect).

However, when the request is first made, it will not be encrypted. An attacker could man-in-the-middle or passively sniff the connection in order to read request data or even prevent it from redirecting to HTTPS. The best solution is to make the change now, and begin rolling out new application code that points only to HTTPS.

Comment: The attack you describe is commonly known as [SSLStrip](https://moxie.org/software/sslstrip/)

Comment: While SSLStrip is one example, it is not the only possibility here.

Comment: Note that Java will not follow a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.  [From the actual bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4620571): *... It's the application's responsibility to follow the redirect.*

Answer (score 0):

Just because you add `https` to your web server does not mean that you have to remove `http`. For example, this very page is available both over [http](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120521/ssl-certificate-in-my-hosting-makes-me-change-my-java-code), and over [https](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120521/ssl-certificate-in-my-hosting-makes-me-change-my-java-code).

While it's certainly a good idea to migrate your Android app to use `https`, you don't have to do it right away: offer both!

Comment: If I not change my java code, and the code send http request and my hosting already have https, Shall I have my request encrypted? This is the important think: Ok i'm not gonna change my java code and I still have GET and POST request with http but this automatically encrypted if I have my web services with SSL?

Comment: Why does it have to be one or the other? Why can't you configure your webserver to accept both http (unencrypted) and https (encrypted)? Your existing java code will continue to request the unencrypted http. If you want your java code to be requesting https, then you _may_ have to modify the code (go look in the Android docs, I'm sure you'll find your answer there).